# Xcode: Disable watch simulator when running app

Tags: objective-c, expecta

I recently updated Xcode and now the watch simulator keeps starting every time I run my app on the regular simulator. How do I disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the iOS Simulator's TaskBar, go to **Hardware** -> **External Displays**. There, **uncheck** the WatchSimulator.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: It's actually under Hardware -> External Displays on the simulator file menu.

Answer (score 0):

Choose Disabled from the Hardware menu's External Displays submenu.